# Using function on tuples on list works in Google Colab, but not on local machine

Tags: python, pandas, list

I can't figure out what's going on. In my google colab environment, I have a dataframe that looks like the below using spaCy's named entity extraction on snippets from NYT:

```
raw_data = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'ents': [[(('PARIS', 'GPE'), 6), (('French', 'NORP'), 3), (('France', 
         'GPE'), 1)],
           [(('CHINA','GPE'), 3), (('British', 'NORP'), 2), (('Hong Kong', 
           'GPE'), 1)],
       [(('Chile','GPE'), 3), (('spanish', 'NORP'), 1), (('Hong Kong', 'GPE'), 
       1)]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

I apply a function to get back only ents where the entity exceeds a count threshold,

```
def limit_ents(ents):
    for i in ents:
        if i[1] >=2:
            return [i[0][0] for i in ents]

df['limit_ents'] = df['ents'].apply(limit_ents)
```

This all works fine in Google Colab, but when I do this on my local machine, I get IndexError: string index out of range pointing to the line in the function "if ent[1] >=2:

Is this a runnning pandas on Linux vs. Windows thing? I'm running pandas 1.1.3 in both places. Am I doing something incredibly stupid?

Thanks for everyone's help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! After much banging my head against the wall, turns out that all I needed to do was to check if the object has type list. I was reading in a *.csv extracted ents and the values for that column were not longer type list - evaluated to False when I did an isinstance. Should've saved my original output as a pickle instead.